# Cant get correct width of fonts char

Tags: java, fonts, java-2d

This is a method that returns awt fonts character as a bufferedimage:

```
private BufferedImage getCharImage(char ch) {
    BufferedImage sizeImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D sizeGraphics = (Graphics2D) sizeImage.getGraphics();
    if (antiAlias) {
        sizeGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    }

    FontMetrics fontMetrics = sizeGraphics.getFontMetrics(font);
    int charwidth = fontMetrics.charWidth(ch);
    if (charwidth <= 0) {
        charwidth = 1;
    }

    int charheight = fontMetrics.getHeight();
    if (charheight <= 0) {
        charheight = fontSize;
    }

    BufferedImage charImage = new BufferedImage(charwidth, charheight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D charGraphics = (Graphics2D) charImage.getGraphics();

    if (antiAlias) {
        charGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    }

    charGraphics.setFont(font);
    charGraphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    charGraphics.drawString(String.valueOf(ch), 0, fontMetrics.getAscent());

    return charImage;
}
```

The problem is that i get incorrect width, and the characters don't fit to crated buffered images. If i would create the buffered image like this `new BufferedImage(charwidth + 10, charheight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);` the characters would fit to images (that means that i get wrong font width). **Why am i facing this prolem and how ca i fix it?** I'm using arialbi.ttf (bold, italic).

This is how the font renders
[image]

**Edit:**

This is how i define the font variable:

```
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream);
    font = font.deriveFont(fontSize);
```

Comment: Please let me know if you want me to clarify something.

Comment: Show how are you defining your `font` variable.

Comment: It looks like `fontSize` is an integer.  Do you mean for it to be a floating point?  There are two `deriveFont()` methods: one for style (integer) and one for size (floating point).

Comment: Nope, it's a float (124f)

Comment: I just tried using arial bold, and everything was absolutely fine... What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because the advance, or `charWidth()` doesn't have much to do with the actual width of the character as defined by the font.

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html#charWidth%28char%29) for `FontMetrics.charWidth(char ch)`:

> The advance is the distance from the leftmost point to the rightmost
>   point on the character's baseline

A character like "g" in Chancery Italic, below the baseline, extends left of the minimum x. Or "s" in the same font extends right of the maximum x, above the baseline. In a straighter font, like Arial Regular, the advance (baseline width) happens to be pretty close to the actual width of the character.

I'm not sure of a good solution besides adding arbitrary padding.

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html

Comment: For anyone interested, the paddings on either side of the character are called left-side bearings and right-side bearings, and could be positive or negative in relation to the advance width. Microsoft has a good illustration [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what is required to get the exact width of a string :

```
FontMetrics fontMetricesForLabel = graphics.getFontMetrics();
double width = fontMetricesForLabel.getStringBounds(label, graphics).getWidth();
```